# Where is the "donut hole" in 3-Torus?

Tags: general-topology

A 3-Torus is a flat manifold. Intuitively, it is like a "cubic room with glass walls" where, as you go through the glass, you return to the room through the opposite wall. This is true in any direction.

A 1-torus is a loop (like a circle) with a "hole" in the topology.

A 2-Torus can be approximately visualized as a "donut" also with a "hole". This visualization or projection explains that the manifold is not simply connected (see the image below).

How can one visualize why a 3-Torus is not simply connected? Where is the "donut hole" in the "cubic glass room"? Why is this "room" not simply connected?

[image: 2-Torus]

Comment: aka an annulus for the 1-d version ?

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee No, unlike an annulus ring, a 1-Torus is a thin line.

Comment: a nice visualization : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zh0I_duLZNQ

Comment: aka an annulus with 0 width ... I've played with tori because you can actually relate modular arithmetic on the surface...

Comment: @EmilioNovati https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_torus#/media/File:Clifford-torus.gif

Comment: It's a similar circular tube as the donut, but in the 4 dimensional space, with donuts as transversal hyperplane sections.

Comment: @Berci You are describing a 2-Torus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 2-torus can be represented as a square with the opposing sides identified.
When we walk through the square in the x-direction and cross its side, we enter the same square from the opposite side. Cross it in the y-direction and the same things happens.

Consider the intersection of the red circles in your picture to represent the square.
Go in one direction, and we make a 'loop' that brings us back to the other side. Pick the other direction, and we make the other 'loop' that brings us back.

Now consider that we draw a third red circle that intersects at the same point. And let it run in a virtual direction so that it does not intersect the torus.
It represents that we extend our square into a cube.
The same horizontal crossings apply that correspond to the red circles - or holes if you will. Note that both red circles correspond to a 'hole'.
And now we can also go up through the ceiling, and make a loop that makes us come back through the floor.

Comment: So a 3-Torus has 3 holes. Makes sense. Does this mean it has genus 3?

Comment: A 3-Torus is not a surface @Hiroyashu :)

Comment: @Axstroo A 3-Torus is a 3D hypersurface of a solid 4D Torus. The "holes" I mention are not a part of the 3-Torus manifold, but they define its genus and whether or not it is simply connected. These "holes" represent the (hyper)volume of the solid Torus under its (hyper)surface.